# CS193P - Assignment 2, descriptionOfTopOfStack:, recursive class method

Tags: objective-c, cs193p

below is a class method that always returns null -when, for example, stack = 2,2,"+" I want it to return "2+2"

In the initial iteration the method correctly  determines the topOfStack is a NSString rather than a NSNumber but is doesn't create NSString 'description' to equal "2+2" by recursive calling

I feel I'm missing something obvious here, am I dealing with the strings correctly....

```
+ (NSString *) descriptionOfTopOfStack: (NSMutableArray * ) stack
{
   NSString *description;

id topOfStack = [stack lastObject]; // get last object
if (topOfStack) [stack removeLastObject]; // then remove it from stack

if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) { // is last object a number?
    return [topOfStack stringValue]; // if so then return it, **done*** 
}
else if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) 
{      
    if ([topOfStack isEqualToString:@"+"])
          {
                 [description stringByAppendingString: [self descriptionOfTopOfStack:stack]];
                 [description stringByAppendingString:@"+"];
                 [description stringByAppendingString: [self descriptionOfTopOfStack:stack]];
          }


   }

   NSLog(@"Description is %@", description);

return description;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method [stringByAppendingString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString%3a) returns an autoreleased string, does not modify the original one. If you want to modify `description` you must do something like

```
description = [description stringByAppendingString: [self descriptionOfTopOfStack:stack]];
```

Besides, writing

```
NSString *description;
```

you are just creating a pointer to a `NSString`, not a `NSString`. Use instead

```
NSString* description = @"";
```

Comment: I realise know that I was expecting to change an immutable string! Doh!